# hard flush_rewrite_rules() not regenerating .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, wordpress-theming

I am currently developing a theme where I want to add two permalinks.
One is redirecting to the index.php with some custom parameters and values (rule stored in the wp_options table), the other is redirecting to a file in my template which offers the admin-ajax.php functionality (rule stored in .htaccess file).

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 
        '^(activate|reset)/([0-9]*)sfa([A-Za-z0-9]*)/?$',
        'index.php?sfa_user=$matches[2]&sfa_password_reset=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'ajax-api/?$',
        str_replace( ABSPATH, '', dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/api/ajax-api.php' )
    );

    flush_rewrite_rules( true );
} );
```

As I am in developement mode I am flushing the rules by executing on the 'init' hook as well 
(*I know this is bad practice but this seems to be the best method for me to check if there is any change in the .htaccess file.*).

**The Problem:**
Even though `flush_rewrite_rules()` resets hard flushing by default I set the parameter to true just to make sure. My first rewrite rule is perfoming very well whereas the .htaccess file is not regenerated until I visit the options-permalink.php page in the backend (where the flush-function is called as well and works?!).

I already tried excecuting `flush_rewrite_rules()` on another hooks as proposed in the Reference.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You should never hook `flush_rewrite_rules` on `init`. It's even worse if it's a hard flush...

Comment: Oh wow — thank you @yivi for your needless comment. As I already pointed out I hooked the function on init for testing purposes. And as I pointed out as well I’m aware of the fact that you should hook it on other actions… Nevertheless this should have no effect on the flushing process itself, right? If you really want to help, please do yourself a favour and read the whole post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution…
`save_mod_rewrite_rules()` is the function which will generate and add rewrite rules. In the Doc it says:

```
/* If the function named 'save_mod_rewrite_rules' exists, it will be called. */
```

This function is part of `wp-admin/includes/misc.php` which is loaded by `wp-admin/includes/admin.php` which is loaded right before the `admin_init` action hook.

Nevertheless you should never flush rewrite rules at any init action hook: [Flush Rewrite Examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Examples)